# Google Firebase - reformat JSON output

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, converters

I'm using Google Firebase which generates JSON with data like this:

```
{
    "tasks": {
        "-LzH6kQjS_nY4P97EONB": {
            "createdBy": "Andrew",
            "date": "\"2020-01-23T11:17:24.213Z\"",
            "description": "Some task description.",
            "done": false
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to convert it to this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": "-LzH6kQjS_nY4P97EONB",
        "createdBy": "Andrew",
        "date": "\"2020-01-23T11:17:24.213Z\"",
        "description": "Some task description.",
        "done": false
    }
]
```

I think I can handle the conversion part (if you Guys don't see some impossible stuff here) but I can't think of way of "returning" converted JSON file so it's always available under the link. Is there a way to do it without much hassle and without risking Firebase security?

Comment: '"returning" converted JSON file so it's always awailable under the link' what do you mean by that? What kind of client needs such a format?

Comment: Qlik needs it in that format, otherwise it splits every object as separate table and gives them suffixes such as "createdBy_u1", "createdBy_u2". "Under the link" - right now I give link to Firebase .json file so probably I need to give other link which gives reformated JSON, or am I mixing things?

Comment: Oh, I see. There are many ways to solve this. How often is data added in Firebase? What client are you using to add data? Do you have access to its code? Do many persons add data at the same time? How often will you read the resulting format? How many elements are there going to be? (like... more than 100?)

Comment: What .json link are you giving at the moment? If you're giving a link to your database root, you might solve your issue by giving a .json link to your "tasks" path.

Comment: @Stratubas It's not root. Code sample from my post is from "tasks" path JSON.
- It's Qlik mashup, I'm using JavaScript to save data (that's why I decided go Firebase because I have no access to PHP etc.),
- Yes I have access to that code.,
- ~20 poeple adding adding at the same - twice per month,
- What do you mean by elements?

Comment: By "elements" I mean entries. With 20 people adding 2 per month, you'll reach 100+ entries within 3 months. Let me post an answer with some possible solutions.

Comment: @Stratubas I've imported this working JSON file to Firebase and it worked. So maybe whole conversion is not required if I can add entries without those auto ID, will check that. Thank you already for so much help!

Comment: It is indeed possible, but tricky. See solution 3 of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Make a [Database Triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that will run each time a task is added at your `tasks` path. That function should use the newly added data to update an array at a different path, like `tasksAsArray`. You can use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) to read the existing array, add the new item and save the new array. Then use that path in the ".json" url for Qlik.
2. Make an [HTTP Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that will read your `tasks` from the database and return an array in your desired format as a response.
3. Modify the clients' code to write data directly in the desired format.

---

With solution 1, as years pass and data grows, the performance of the transaction will start declining, but probably not noticeably. If you don't need very old data in your response, instead of only adding tasks in the array, you can also remove old data from it, to limit the size of the array.

---

With solution 2, you can [Limit Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries) to include only the tasks of the last few months or years.

---

Solution 3 requires clients to know precisely how many tasks there already are*, so that they would add the new task at the proper index. You said there would be 20 concurrent users, so there is a risk that multiple clients will write at the same path, and overwrites will happen.

To prevent overwrites, you can use a database rule like [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data), and handle the errors on the client (retry with a correct index).

You can also do database transactions from the clients, but that would make adding tasks slower, as your array becomes large. A cloud function doesn't care if it takes a few seconds to do something, but a user cares :)

*To find how many tasks there already are, you can read the whole array and count the elements. Instead, you can make a background cloud function that would maintain a `taskCount` path, which would be just that: the number of tasks. Then clients can simply read that number.

Comment: What a great list, thank you very much! I will start with #3 as I mentioned in original post. Thank you!